# GCC inline ASM guarantees

Tags: c++, c, assembly, inline-assembly

I think this is a simple question but I could not find anything.
If I write

```
void bar()
{
    {
        void *rax = 0/* ...*/, *rbx = 0/* ... */;
        asm volatile ("movq %0, %%rax; movq %1, %%rbx;" : : "m"(rax), "m"(rbx));
        goto foo;    
    }

    {
        foo:
        void* rax, *rbx;
        asm volatile ("movq %%rax, %0; movq %%rbx, %1;" : "=m"(rax), "=m"(rbx));

        // LOTS OF CODE
    }
}
```

is it guaranteed that I can fetch the values of rax/rbx before any other code in the second block is run?

Comment: Seems like an XY question - what are you ACTUALLY trying to solve?

Comment: I am writing a function hooking library for C++. I want to use registers not used by the ABI to transfer a userdata pointer to the hook function.

Comment: So why don't you write an assembler wrapper that calls the actual function? That's the traditional method of solving this problem.

Comment: By the way, did you mean to read FROM the variable called rax into the register, or the other way around in the first assembler section? It seems strange to load 0 into a register in such a long-winded way.

Comment: 1.) I use an assembler wrapper to call the function - but I try to transfer a userdata pointer to the called function so I can invoke a function object instead of a regular C function.

Comment: 2.) The first asm statement copies the content of the variables rax/rbx into the registers rax/rbx. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `volatile` with `asm` in gcc, will guarantee that the compiler doesn't re-order the satements. However, it's not guaranteed that the compiler doesn't add extra code between the `foo:` label and the inline `asm` statement. And of course, this means that you can't rely on register values being preserved in that section - I haven't managed to come up with a distinct example of that, but I'm pretty certain the compiler does NOT guarantee that this can't happen.

Answer (score 3):

No -- the compiler hooks up the in/out values based on the contraints to the registers/memory locations it has allocated immediately before/after the asm statement, and assumes that other registers are not affected.  So in your case it might have put something important into `%%eax` or `%%ebx` which you are clobbering (which might cause a crash or other misbehavior).

Any time you use fixed registers in an asm statement you MUST list those registers in the clobbers list (unless you're using a constraint that maps to a particular register).  So at the very least you would need:

```
asm volatile ("movq %0, %%rax; movq %1, %%rbx;" : : "m"(rax), "m"(rbx) : "rax", "rbx");
```

for your asm statement -- but even then there's no guarentee that the compiler won't put
something else into `%%eax` or `%%ebx` after your first asm block and before the second (clobbering the values you are trying to save.)

Comment: Thanks for your response - I think I have to be more specific. I only included the first block to show the behaviour - the first is **not** created by a compiler but by myself manually writing instruction bytes into a buffer and executing the buffer. Sorry about that. I only need to know if I can rely on the inline asm statement in the second block executed first and before the code following in the second block uses them for something else.

Comment: @Ethon: Then it sounds like you probably want the `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"`, `"S"`, and `"D"` constraints to bind to specific registers